# Android/ Java SDKS error

Tags: android, xamarin

I have recently updated the xamarin for android in visual studio and I am getting the following error.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Error finding Android/Java SDKs
System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'D:\Setups\android-ndk-r12b-windows-x86_64\android-ndk-r12b\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\toolchains'.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1.CommonInit()
   at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1..ctor(String path, String originalUserPath, String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption, SearchResultHandler`1 resultHandler, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.Directory.EnumerateDirectories(String path, String searchPattern)
   at Xamarin.Android.Build.Utilities.AndroidSdkBase.Initialize(String androidSdkPath, String androidNdkPath, String javaSdkPath)
   at Xamarin.Android.Build.Utilities.AndroidSdk.Refresh(String androidSdkPath, String androidNdkPath, String javaSdkPath)  App2
```

Can anyone help me out?
Thanks.

Comment: Did you check that the path is correct?

Comment: Yes, path is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A re-install of xamarin worked for me.

Comment: How you re-install of xamarin can you tell me please?

Comment: @pArthsavadiya Just uninstall it from controlPanel -> Programs -> uninstall A Program -> Xamarin Universal Installer. And then re-install it from xamarin's site or using visual studio repair.

Answer (score 1):

I just created a empty folder named **toolchains** at the specified location in error. Clean the code and rebuild.

Error got resolved.

Maybe it help somebody as it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you did an install of Xamarin, configured the NDK, then later did an upgrade to the latest VS and Xamarin, this issue seems to happen. It seems the folder path just wants to points to the root instead of the toolchains folder in more recent versions. IE..

Instead of specifying your NDK folder (as seen in your exception:

```
..\android-ndk-xx\prebuilt\windows-xxx_xx\bin\toolchain
```

After updating, specify:

```
..\android-ndk-xx
```

This solved it for me.